# INSERT INTO SELECT How to return set of insert Ids

Tags: mysql

I have a working `INSERT INTO SELECT` query which inserts records into a new table based on the results of the select. Simple.

```
INSERT INTO my_table (a, b, c)
SELECT a, b, c FROM my_table 
WHERE x=y;
```

How do I get the newly created primary key IDs from the `INSERT` part of this query so that I can use them to update another table? (The primary key is the only unique reference)

I have read that `INSERT INTO SELECT` only supports inserting into one table per query, so that's out of the question. How can this be accomplished (using MyISAM engine)?

Comment: Create a stored procedure and insert records individually using loop so that it will be easy to get last inserted id. store this ids and return

Comment: Yes, I guess that's the obvious solution. But I'd rather sacrifice that solution for performance and cleaner code if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu can select your data in a temp Table, then run cursor on that while inserting rows u ll have PK

```
     DECLARE @tempTable TABLE(
    a VARCHAR(MAX),
    b VARCHAR(MAX),
    c VARCHAR(MAX)
    )

    INSERT INTO @tempTable(a,b,c)
    SELECT a,b,c FROM my_table WHERE x=y

DECALRE @a DATATYPE;
Declare @b DATATYPE;
Declare @c DATATYPE;

DECLARE cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT * FROM @tempTable

OPEN cursor 

FETCH NEXT FROM PropertyCursor INTO @a, @b,@c
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO my_table(a,b,c)
VALUES(@a,@b,@c)
DECALRE @PrimaryKey INT = SCOPE_IDENTITY();//THis line will give u the PK so u can work with it and then below move to next row
FETCH NEXT FROM cursor INTO @a, @b,@c
END

CLOSE cursor 
DEALLOCATE cursor
```

Comment: Apurav, can you be a bit more specific? So, assuming I put the results of the SELECT into a temporary table, how would this yield the primary key?

Comment: see my edit, after ur insert u will have a local variable to save the Generated PrimaryKey, to work with it. Also use the right datatype for ur variables.